Modulating a DC power supply (for a impedance measurement)
I'd like to determine the output impedance of a 4-20mA, 3-wire transmitter for different frequencies. Then, with the help of an abacus (response of a first-order low-pass filter), I'll need to find Rx and Cx.
Here's my test setup:

My calculation will be (for each frequency):
$$
Z=\frac{\Delta VB}{\Delta VA}.5000
$$
I have a power supply with three isolated outputs (0-60V max) and a function generator embedded in my oscilloscope, but it's not as easy to connect them as in my diagram because I don't know the max output current of my signal generator.
Oscilloscope with WaveGen
https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/7018-06411/data-sheets/5992-3484.pdf
Power supply
https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/3121-1003/data-sheets/EDU36311A-Triple-Output-Bench-Power-Supply.pdf
How can I make my power supply variable? Is there a simple way to do it with common components? Do you have an idea?
Thx.

This is not how I would measure "output Impedance" by including the input voltage. I would use an external current source and measure voltage-dependent output impedance with an external floating AC source using a low f square or triangle wave to span many harmonic decades.  Is that 5k your End-Of-Line-Resistance for fault sensing?  BTW 3 wire Tx's are prone to interference since they are unbalanced impedance.  Does this matter to you? What is your immunity spec?

Is this just a short distance analog loop sensor?  If not what is the cable impedance and length?

@D.A.S. I'm very interested in a diagram of your proposed output impedance for my transmitter. This is a qualification test requested by the HART Foundation. The 5000 Ohms resistance and the specific test frequencies are imposed on me. The aim is to compare the impedance response with a HART Foundation graph to determine Rx and Cx. On this graph, there are several impedance responses to help you get your bearings. This is not an EMC immunity test. Thank you.

HART Fundation : https://www.fieldcommgroup.org/technologies/hart HART is the global standard for sending and receiving digital information across the 4-20mA

Thank you. To save me time I won't download their specifications, but can you tell me the maximum bit rate? To determine RX and CX simply use the X:1 probe divider matching a square wave to modulate the  stepped current to get a square wave out. Then the Voltage ratio determines the Rx/5k ratio and Cload/Cx ratio

Include the signal generator Rs with 5000 ohms when doing the calculation if not using an Op Amp with near 0 Ohms with a suitable GBW. You can even use a Logic astable square wave and measure it's <50 and a add a series + pullup to make it step from 4.5 to 5V with a 10:1 divider like 120~130 ohm series and 20 ohm pull up for and Req of 20||180 ohm source to add to 5000 calculation for Rx,Cx

If that is Ok I'll write an answer  the squareness of the output will tell me the impedance of the useable BW. To make a matched impedance perfect square wave, sqrt(L/C )=Zo must match the cable (200 ?) so a series L will be small like Cx. Typ 0.5nH/mm

@D.A.S., The maximum bit rate is 1200 baud/s. Many thanks. I'd like a reply with a diagram if that's possible for you.

Is the cable long ?  What impedance? Or pF/m
